# how to fix "argument 'files' might be null" while making an arrayadapter?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

I want to make a mediaplayer and it always throws nullpointerexception. I'am stuck at this point here is my code:

```
package MRT.MRT.MRT0012;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Handler handler=new Handler();
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
    ListView listView;
    Runnable exit=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            backdoublepressed=false;
        }
    };
    boolean backdoublepressed=false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        listView=findViewById(R.id.list);
        File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Musics");
        File[] files=file.listFiles();
        ArrayAdapter<File> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,files);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activitymain_menu,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(backdoublepressed){
            MainActivity.this.finish();
        }
        else{
            backdoublepressed=true;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"press back again to exit",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            handler.postDelayed(exit,3000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case(R.id.exit):{MainActivity.this.finish();break;}
            case(R.id.setting):{
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SettingActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

the exception starts from declaring and initializing the files variable with file.listFiles(); and is there any mistake that I made?

```
   File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Musics");
    File[] files=file.listFiles();
    ArrayAdapter<File> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,files);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I would really appreciate if someone could solve this problem.

Comment: If `files` is null, you should assign an empty File[] array to it, based on what you've described.

Comment: can you explain it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in this code is ok no problem the only problem that might be is, is there any folder named Musics in your directory I think there is no such folder. Create the folder and everything work fine.

Answer (score 3):

argument 'files' might be null is not an error, it is a warning emitted by a linter tool, presumably Android Studio. You are free to ignore it.

The result of the `listFiles()` method may be null; this is the case for error conditions, such as the path not existing at all, or if your process has no rights to list the contents of it. This is bad API design; real java fixes this (the java.nio.file API), but I don't think that's available in android.

Adding a null check will make the warning go away. for example:

```
if (files == null) files = new File[0]; // treat failure the same as an empty directory.
```

Whether that's appropriate – that's up to you to decide.